# Pass JSON to Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, ios, json, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want my users to navigate to my web page (Start page) when clicking on Firebase Dynamic Link (FDL) and my app users to go to a specific page (here I need extra data as JSON).

**here is my code:**

```
            val dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("{products:...some custom JSON}"))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("https://mydomain.page.link")
            .setAndroidParameters(DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build()) //if set, a click on dynamic link will open android app
            .setIosParameters(DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.foodhatapp.foodhatios").build()) 
            .setSocialMetaTagParameters(DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                .setTitle("Bismillah, FOODHHAAAT")
                .setDescription("please click and order at foodhat!")
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://h2866694.stratoserver.net/foodhat/images/products/62-1733-1f644aa6-30af-4237-9478-68a114d7600f.png"))
                .build())
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                i("teeeeest", it.shortLink.toString())
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                i("teeeeest", "error at creating dynamic link...show popup to user..." +
                        "maybe his internet is broken etc... please check your internet connection and try again later")
            }
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass JSON in setLink()-Section...but where can I pass a JSON correctly?

I am getting an `FailureException`

I know that setLink() expects a well formated URI...But I want to pass JSON to my apps and for web just navigate to the start page so the root URL of web page...

How to realise that?

Comment: whats the reason of sending a json in dynamic link?

Comment: Because in the target Page in the app I am showing a food product...and instead of passing the product id in the url of dynamic link, I want to pass the product JSON with all infos of that product via dynmaic link and when the app receives the JSON I can just extract the JSON adn show product infos wihtin the page in the app...This Way I don´t have to make a network request to get product info...

I just pass the product infos as JSON when creating a dynamic link...thats the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append your json data in the link itself like this...

```
String json = "{}";//convert your json into string
 String link = "http://yourdomainlink.com/?jsondata=" + json;
```

Set the link

.setLink(Uri.parse(link));

Then retrive the json like this(Code is in java)

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            String json = deepLink.getQueryParameter("jsondata"); 

                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Hope this helps